# Execute perl script using mason template

Tags: perl, cpan, mason

I have installed Mason module from cpan. Now i am executing my first program using mason template.

**first_mason.mc**

```
% my $name = "Mason";
    Hello world! Welcome to <% $name %>.
```

**first_mason.pl**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Mason;
my $mason = Mason->new(comp_root => '...');
print $mason->run('first_mason.mc')->output;
```

This throws an **error** as follows

> first_mason.mc is not an absolute path at C:/Perl/site/lib/Mason/Request.pm line 256**

***Note***

I am placing both files in the path where mason is installed(to find an installation path ,i used `perldoc -l Mason`) and executed a program using `perl first_mason.pl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@stevenl fully answers your question. Simply don't blindly copy the Synopsis from the [Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason) docs, need read the docs too. :) E.g. in the example code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Mason;
my $mason = Mason->new(comp_root => '...');
print $mason->run('/foo')->output;
```

you need replace

- and the *shebang line* `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` with the real path to your perl interpreter
- the `'...'` with the real path in the filesystem, where your component are, e.g.

```
comp_root => '/some/real/path/here/where/my/component/root/is'
```

---

However,  I wrote this answer mainly with a reason: if you want use the Mason for the **web-app** development, check the [Poet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Poet) module too. It GREATLY simplifies the whole process, and you will not need care about many-many things. E.g. after installing the `Poet` you can simply:

```
poet new MyApp
myapp/bin/run.pl
```

and you will immediately get (*without **any*** configuration) an WORKING web-app, and you could access it in your browser at http://localhost:5000. Your `component_root` will be inside of the `myapp` directory as `myapp/comps`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to put your files in the directory where Mason is installed:

- Perl should know where to find Mason when you import it with `use` (assuming your perl installation is correct).
- Mason will know where to find the .mc file via the `comp_root` argument.
- The component name needs to be specified as a path relative to `comp_root`, always beginning with `/`.
- You need to leave out the `.mc` from the component name.

So, if you place the 2 files in your home directory, then the script should look like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Mason;
my $mason = Mason->new(comp_root => $HOME_DIR); # where $HOME_DIR is `C:\User\your_name`
print $mason->run('/first_mason')->output;
```

From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mason/lib/Mason/Manual/Components.pod#The-component-root-and-component-paths):

> ### The component root and component paths
>
> When you use Mason, you specify a component root that all component
>   files live under. Thereafter, any component will be referred to by its
>   virtual path relative to the root, rather than its full filename.
>
> For example, if the component root is '/opt/web/comps', then the
>   component path '/foo/bar.mc' refers to the file
>   '/opt/web/comps/foo/bar.mc'.